# The possibility of swapping a value to a different value (absolute difference is two)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, optimization

For example, the original vector is (2, 4, 1, 0).

After swapping, it can be (1, 0, 2, 4) or (0, 1, 4, 2).

The second outcome is what I want because every absolute value of the difference between the original values and the new values are equal to or more than 2, say|2-0|=2, |4-1|>2, |1-4|>2, |0-2|=2.

However, the first outcome  is not what I want because for example |2-1|<2.

How to decide whether the original vector can be swapped to a new vector where every absolute value of the difference between the original values and the new values are equal to or more than 2?

Any suggestions? Many thanks.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer I posted yesterday?

Comment: Earth to Orchard's, come in, please.

Answer (score 1):

First, put your entries in increasing order, $a_1\le a_2\le\cdots\le a_{2n}$. Then in your original vector swap $a_i$ with $a_{n+i}$ for each $i$. If that doesn't work, nothing will.

In your example, you go $0,1,2,4$, then swap $0$ with $2$, and $1$ with $4$ (as you did).

You have to fudge this a little, if your vector has an odd number of entries.

Comment: Hi, your approach seems good. What if the number of values is odd, say 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Comment: As I wrote, you have to fudge it a little. Why not think about it, and see whether you can figure out what to do? If you give it a go, but don't get anywhere, I'll come back to help.